# How to assign complex expressions to variables using @ in shell

Tags: shell

I try to set value to variable indx by using another varibale lineId.

```
@ indx = ($lineId-1)*4 + 1
```

However, the above method can't work given the following error.

```
@: Badly formed number.
```

Instead, if split the single line to two, it works.

```
@ indx = $lineId - 1
@ indx = $indx * 4 + 1
```

Thanks for pointing out my problem.

Comment: Which shell is this?

Comment: Thanks for your concern @thatotherguy. The shell I assume is cshell. The problem is not solved completely. I guess cshell is unhappy with indx = ($lineId-1)*4 + 1, which has parenthesis. I use expr command to waive this issue, yet I still hope to understand the root cause. Thanks for any hint.